# Mobile app requires user to pick a number (min: 10, max: 30, increment: 0.25). Should I use an input field, picker, or something else?

Tags: mobile, input

One of the requirements for my application is that the user has to pick one number between the ranges and in the increment stated above. If I did a mobile options picker, there'd be 80 options. Do you guys have any advice on how to best approach this?

Comment: Actually 81 values, not 80, unless either end of the range is excluded.

Comment: @BryceLarkin will the user only enter the number once or does the user need to enter the number more then once?

Comment: @KevinM. They would be entering it more than once.

Comment: Does the user need to see what happens as the number is adjusted by different amounts?

Comment: @bace1000 No. We are trying to collect this information from them in a form. It's just that the values have to be in increments of 0.25.

Answer (score 1):

One way to reduce the complexity is to split the number picking into two parts.

Then you could use a swiping number picker like this that would work good on mobile:
[image: number swiping]

Since you have quite a lot of numbers another good solution could be a popup dialog that is somewhat similar to a calendar:

[image: calendar style dialog]

Answer (score 0):

[image: example]

I am sharing the basic of what would be simple for user to  relate with.